# Como alinhar o menu dropdown com o texto?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-3

Estou com dificuldade para alinhar o meu menu `dropdown`, todo o formulário e inclusive o texto que deveria acompanhar o menu `dropdown` esta certo. Alguma dica?

Ex.:
Resultado obtido:  |`dropdown`| Escolha um ingrediente:

Resultado **esperado**: Escolha um ingrediente: |`dropdown`|

Código do meu menu `dropdown`

```
<div class="form-group">Ingredientes:
<SELECT NAME="ingredientes"  class="col-md-4 control-label" required="1">
            <option Selecione...</option>
            <?php
            while($dados3 = mysql_fetch_array($q3))
            {   
            ?>
             <option value="<?=$dados3['id_ingredientes'] ?>">
            <?=$dados3['nome'] ?>
            </option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>

    </SELECT>
</div>
```

Print do menu:

> [image: o problema]

Comment: insira o "escolha um ingrediente" dentro de um span para ficar ao lado ou um li no "escolha um ingrediente" e outro no select para ficar abaixo, caso seja para ficar antes, use span e a propriedade position relative e float left já no select use position relative e float right ficará um ao lado do outro

Comment: tem um erro sem seu option, está <option selecoone...></option> mude para <option>selecione</option>

Comment: @flourigh obrigado por responder, eu não sei se entendi o que você quis dizer, sou meio novo no php. Mas eu gostaria que ficasse primeiro a palavra ingrediente e depois as opções

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se compreendi direito, tente assim:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ingredientes" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Escolha um ingrediente</label>
        <select name="ingredientes" id="ingredientes" class="col-md-4 control-label" required="1">
            <option>Selecione</option>
            <?php
            while($dados3 = mysql_fetch_array($q3)) {   
            ?>
            <option value="<?= $dados3['id_ingredientes'] ?>">
                <?= $dados3['nome'] ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sempre dê uma conferida na documentação do Bootstrap, pode ajudar http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, era isso mesmo!!!!